# android webview issues

Tags: android

i have created a webview

```
    <WebView  
    android:id="@+id/webview_compontent"
    android:layout_marginTop = "10dp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_weight="1.0"   
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
/>
```

and in my class.java file

```
    webView  = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview_compontent);

    //Need to enable scrollbars when in zoom
    webView.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(true); 
    webView.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(true); 

    webView.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);

    //Page is bigger than view so fit it inside the view
    webView.setInitialScale(40);

    //Enable zooming
    webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);

    webView.loadUrl("www.xyz.com");
    webView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());

    //To disable the link clicks on the page
    webView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return true;
        }
    });
private class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;
    }
}
```

My problem is that i want to diable all the link clicks inside webview but allow zooming with vertical and horizontal scrolls so that the user can zoom and read the text.If i set  "webView.setOnTouchListener" to "ture" my webview does not respond to click events which i want but zoom control also stops which i want to be enabled. How can i filter zoom and link clicks event and enable/disable the view accordingly.

Please help me how to go about this.

Thanks

Comment: I think you should remove this line view.loadUrl(url);

Comment: I think you have to try private class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
       // view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;
    }
} try and let me know what happen..

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answers.But i got it going by adding

```
        webView.setClickable(false); //To disable link clicks
```

and

```
   webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true); //Enable zooming
```

Comment: check above comment. which is the solution i think.